# In CSS, how do I horizontally center child elements, overlapping them as needed to fit in the parent's width without wrapping?

Tags: css, row, overlap, overlapping, playing-cards

I'm trying to create an HTML/CSS element that represents a hand of playing cards.

I have a parent `<div>` container with a fixed height and a 100% width. It contains a variable number of child `<div>`s (cards), each having the same height and the same width as each other.

I'm trying to do this:

- Keep the child `<div>`s on a single horizontal row (no wrapping)
- Center the child `<div>`s
- Horizontally overlap the child `<div>`s as needed whenever the parent container isn't wide enough to show them all side-by-side.
- Preserve the parent `<div>`'s dimensions. (The parent box shouldn't change, regardless of how many child `<div>`s it contains)

Is this possible?

I tried something like this, but no luck:

```css
.parent {
  height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  ...
</div>
```

^ This does a fine job whenever the parent contain is wide enough to fit all of the child `<div>`s side-by-side. But, when the parent isn't that wide, the child `<div>`s do not overlap with each other. Instead, the children exceed the parent's boundaries. (Kids today, amiright?)

I've also tried 'float'ing the child divs and using margin-left:calc(20% - 100px), but that doesn't work for a couple reasons: floated elements can wrap to new lines, and the margin-left value would need to be different depending on how many child elements there are (which can change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with a CSS-only solution, you could try out [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Below I applied `display:  flex` to the `.parent` which allowed the `.child` nodes to be flexed within `.parent` forcing them to equal widths. Within each child I added `position: absolute` to a pseudo element (could just as easily be done with a real element) to act as the actual content. In your case the card display.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 110px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(100% - 96px);
  padding: 48px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
}

.child:hover:after {
  z-index: 1;
}

.child:after {
  content: "A♠";
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid red;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```